# JUNG: Loading Graph nodes in same location

Tags: java, graph, nodes, jung

I'm new to JUNG. I have created nodes in a Graph. Now when ever I run the program I get nodes with different location. How can I load the nodes I created in same location everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of going about this.

(1) Get the nodes where you want them, and then save the positions for later use.  For example, you can use `PersistentLayoutImpl` (if you want to serialize the entire graph), or store some kind of map from vertex identifier to layout position.

(2) Specify a consistent random seed when you create the layout.  You'll do this via the initializer; see `AbstractLayout` for details..  (Not all layouts expose this capability, you might need to hack one to provide your own initializer.)

(3) Use a layout that doesn't have any random elements.